# Micro-fiction covering the beginning of the solar system to the development of humans: "Dust makes rocks, rocks make meat, meat starts to think."

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, flash-fiction

Looking to identify a micro-fiction (micro-non-fiction?) that covers the beginning of the solar system to the development of thinking humans in a quirky paragraph. I vaguely recall it being short sentences, something like "Dust makes rocks, rocks make meat, meat starts to think." Possibly narrated from alien viewpoint?

Comment: This is a good overview, welcome to SFF! However, unless this is actually from an aliens viewpoint or similar I’m not sure if this is on topic. This might be better to ask over on [literature.se], either that or could you [edit] this to expand on how it may be science fictional/fantastical and anything else you remember? For example, when you read this and how old it would be?

Comment: I can't guarantee that it is from an alien viewpoint, but as it's a dim memory I wouldn't rule it out. Science fiction was the only kind of adult fiction I read in the sixties and seventies, which was when I think I read this. "Rocks make meat, meat begins to think" is the kind of quirky locution I wouldn't expect "Normal" writers to indulge in, but I'd expect thought and wordplay that is "out of the box"  from SF writers.

Comment: That sort of pithy summary sounds a lot like something that Terry Pratchett would write, but 60s/70s is too early and he's fantasy not scifi, and I don't know any of his stories that cover that sort of topic.

Comment: I'm calling it micro-fiction because it's very short and possibly has a fictional narrator., But from  another perspective , one could argue that the cosmology/evolution that it paints with such a broad brush is science fact, though expressed almost poetically. We ARE meat that thinks, made of non-organic elements. That's why I wonder if it might have been published in a science fiction magazine, since some of them occasionally published real-world science as well as SF.

Answer (score 3):

There is a story called  “They’re Made out of Meat” which is somewhat similar to the story described. It does not describe the beginning of the solar system or the evolution of humans, but it is from an alien viewpoint, where aliens discuss the existence of thinking creatures made entirely out of meat.

> "I'm not asking you, I'm telling you. These creatures are the only sentient race in the sector and they're made out of meat."
>
> "Maybe they're like the Orfolei. You know, a carbon-based intelligence that goes through a meat stage."
>
> "Nope. They're born meat and they die meat. We studied them for several of their life spans, which didn't take too long. Do you have any idea the life span of meat?" 
> <sub><sup>*[- They’re Made out of Meat (Terry Bisson)](https://www.mit.edu/people/dpolicar/writing/prose/text/thinkingMeat.html)*</sup></sub>

The aliens are baffled by the existence of meat that can think, and the story is written with fairly short sentences.

> "Spare me. Okay, maybe they're only part meat. You know, like the Weddilei. A meat head with an electron plasma brain inside."
>
> "Nope. We thought of that, since they do have meat heads like the Weddilei. But I told you, we probed them. They're meat all the way through."
>
> "No brain?"
>
> "Oh, there is a brain all right. It's just that the brain is made out of meat!"
>
> "So... what does the thinking?"
>
> "You're not understanding, are you? The brain does the thinking. The meat."  
> <sub><sup>*[- They’re Made out of Meat (Terry Bisson)](https://www.mit.edu/people/dpolicar/writing/prose/text/thinkingMeat.html)*</sup></sub>

The details don’t all match but it does seem somewhat similar to the story description.

Comment: I'm familiar with the delightful  “They’re Made out of Meat,” but that's not the one. The one I'm looking for is maybe a half dozen very short sentences in all, in the style I posted.   I was always taken by the stark simplicity of rock turning to meat, and meat starting to think, as a way of describing us. I suspect this was most likely written in the sixties or seventies.

Comment: @CarolMaltby Thanks for your response! :) I will keep looking and maybe someone will find it.